# cscart {{o._tax_name}} value in documents - invoice and order summary

Tags: cs-cart

I wish to add more values to product table in cs- cart documents.

In my country we have requirements for tax name for each product included in invoice.

How can I add value of {{o._tax_name}} into product table in documents invoice and order summary in cscart ?

Comment: Have you created such a field for your product?

Comment: Same problem for me.. I think this file should be extended /app/Tygh/Template/Snippet/Table/ProductVariable.php or create a new custom snippet "ProductVariableExtended"

Answer (score 0):

You could modify or add inside your own addon at path:

```
/app/addons/my_changes/schemas/snippets/order_products_table.post.php
```

the code that looks something like this:

```
$schema['custom_tax_name'] = array(
    'class' => '\Tygh\Template\Document\Variables\GenericVariable',
    'data' => function (\Tygh\Template\Snippet\Table\ItemContext $context) {
        $data = array();
        $product = $context->getItem();
        $data['tax_name'] = getTaxName($custom_val); //you could have function here to get whatever your needs are

        return $data;
    },
    'arguments' => array('#context', '#config', '@formatter'),
    'attributes' => array(
        'tax_name'
    )
);
```

After this, **clear your cache** and then you will see inside Menu: Documents - order.invoice the new value that already created, like this:

```
{{ custom_tax_name.tax_name }}
```